How to view the content of a rauc bundle (raucb file)?
I have an update.raucb file that contains an update for an embedded device. The file is a so called rauc bundle.
How can I view the content of a .raucb file, like manifest.raucm and root file system?

To extract the content of a rauc bundle to squashfs-root, do:
unsquashfs update.raucb

This will create a folder squashfs-root that contains a manifest.raucm file and the root file system. One probably needs to mount the rootfs. For example:
cd squashfs-root/
mkdir mnt/
sudo mount update.ext4 mnt/

